# Why are the navbar items being moved along with the logo when trying to move it to the left?

Tags: html, css, debugging, bootstrap-4

When I try to move `.logo` to the left, all of the other navbar items (Home, Features, Pricing, Disabled) also get moved to the left as well.

I just want to move `.logo` to the left, not the other navbar items.  I should also add that I'm using Bootstrap 4.

What's causing this to happen and how can I fix it?

Here's `index.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topSection container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <img class="logo" src="https://99designs-start-attachments.imgix.net/alchemy-pictures/2016%2F02%2F22%2F04%2F24%2F31%2Fb7bd820a-ecc0-4170-8f4e-3db2e73b0f4a%2F550250_artsigma.png?auto=format&ch=Width%2CDPR&w=250&h=250"/>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's `index.css`:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

.logo {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.topSection {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAA1BMVEWA8iEsrLU7AAAASElEQVR4nO3BgQAAAADDoPlTX+AIVQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwDcaiAAFXD1ujAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: inherit;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1679px) {
    img {
        max-width: 30%;
        max-height: 30%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `justify-content-end` to `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">`. This will move the content to the right and keep the logo on the left.

I also edited this (included in CSS below):

```
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    display: block;
}
```

This will position your navbar items on the right and your image on the left.

Codepen using your code: https://codepen.io/brooksrelyt/pen/MLbZmq

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

    <title>App</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topSection container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <img class="logo" src="https://99designs-start-attachments.imgix.net/alchemy-pictures/2016%2F02%2F22%2F04%2F24%2F31%2Fb7bd820a-ecc0-4170-8f4e-3db2e73b0f4a%2F550250_artsigma.png?auto=format&ch=Width%2CDPR&w=250&h=250"/>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;

}

img {
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50%;
    display: block;
}

.logo {
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.topSection {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAA1BMVEWA8iEsrLU7AAAASElEQVR4nO3BgQAAAADDoPlTX+AIVQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwDcaiAAFXD1ujAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: inherit;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1679px) {
    img {
        max-width: 10%;
        max-height: 10%;
    }
}
```

Comment: it did move content to the right but whenever I still move my logo to the left, the contents still move to the right along with the logo

Comment: How do you want it to look?

Comment: I want the logo all the way to the left and the contents all the way to the right.  The problem's that they're each glued to eachother so whatever I do to one affects the other.  I believe my CSS is kind of off.